# difference between rebar and sinan

Tags: build, erlang

What is the difference between [sinan](http://erlware.github.com/sinan) build system and [rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar). Some pros and cons.

Comment: And how does agner fit into this?

Comment: If this question were more "filled-out", it might be a good fit for [programmers.se], but I don't think it's quite there yet. Please [edit] the post to include more details of what you're looking for in a build system, your specific requirements, etc., then flag the post for moderator attention. (There's enough non-migration close votes now that it requires moderator attention to migrate elsewhere. I've got hopes that this question can be improved enough to make a great question for [programmers.se].)